# Fill geom_point() based on two conditions: either on column value, or if value is 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know how to ggplot a graph with dots that are sized according to some variable:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = value))
```

How do I add a condition where if there is a `0` in `value`, the point is grey or outlined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a new variable after `value`. This new variable will take two values `(0,1)`. Use that as an `aes()` for `color`.

Here an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

First create `new_var` according to your needs:

```
# new_var is 0 if wt>5, otherwise is 1
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(new_var = ifelse(wt>5, 0, 1))
 #mutate(new_var = ifelse(value==0, 0, 1)) # in your case do this instead
```

Plot using `new_var` as a new aesthetics:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=wt, color = as.factor(new_var))) + # add as.factor() to color accordingly
  scale_color_manual(values=c("gray", "black")) # custom coloring the points
  #+ guides(color=FALSE) # this removes the color legend
```

[image]

Of course you can remove later the second legend and do other improvements.

---

Another example, with a different `shape`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=wt, color = as.factor(new_var)), shape=21, fill="black") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "black")) +
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]